# Azure EvenHubs Spring boot samples not running in Cloud Shell

Tags: spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud

I try to test the [Azure-Samples eventhubs example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/eventhubs/spring-cloud-azure-starter-eventhubs/eventhubs-client)

I want to execute it from the Cloud Shell and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: ERROR: Tenant shouldn't be specified for Cloud Shell account
```

I was checking the code and the tenant is not used in any place in this simple example. So how to run it in the Cloud Shell and, in general, what is the reason of the error and how to avoid that error?

Comment: Are you passing the `tenant Id` while logging into `Azure`. Can you try like this 
 `az login --tenant <tenantID>` .

Comment: @Jahnavi It is executed from the Cloud Shell. So all credentials are ready to use. I understand that no login is required. Right?

Comment: Ya. Actually, I just want to know where exactly the authentication is failing. While running the above git samples?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Check out the project and follow the few simple steps.

Answer (score 0):

As I followed all the step in the above. creating the application of spring cloud azure starter EventHub to send and receive messages with azure event hubs.

- We used terraform file format to create resource group and EventHub namespace as well through azure CLI.

```
provider  "azurerm"{
features{}
}

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "examplegroup"  {
    name = "springterra"
    location = "West Europe"
    }

resource  "azurerm_storage_account"  "example"  {
    name = "mystorage01acc"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.location
    account_tier = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "GRS"
    }

resource  "azurerm_eventhub_namespace"  "example"  {
    name = "evnt01hub"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
    sku = "Standard"
    capacity = 2
    tags = {
    environment = "Production"
    }
}
```

[image]

- Created a spring boot app by adding event Hub starter dependencies in pom.xml file to send or receive messages from the event Hub.

Everything works fine as per the above document. In my reproduce I didn't find the tenant ID which you got in the error exception.

Mostly, these type of errors will get while login with Azure CLI only.

**Reference's:**

- [How to install the Azure CLI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)
- [azurerm_eventhub | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventhub)

Comment: There are no problem creating the infrastruture. The error is when executing the spring cloud application.

Comment: Check your application's configuration and make sure that you are not specifying a tenant ID for a Cloud Shell account.